# Should we make a meta post devoted to language learning resources for each language?

Tags: discussion

What I'm proposing is a *megathread* of sorts, containing language learning resources for lots of different values, or at least links to questions related to such resources for each language. I'm asking because I've noticed many questions asking for language learning resources in *language A/B/C*, and I think it would be somewhat useful to refer new users of our site to a (somewhat) comprehensive list of resources for each language. What are your thoughts? Is such an undertaking worth the time and effort it would entail?

---

Here are some examples of questions I'm describing: [a question about Greek learning resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/877/online-platform-for-learning-greek), [Slovenian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/736/are-there-any-online-courses-for-learning-slovenian), [Tagalog](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/880/anything-similar-to-duolingo-for-learning-tagalog/2737#2737), [West Punjabi](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2341/seeking-west-punjabi-learning-resources), etc.

---

What the list I'm suggesting would look like is this:

*Below are links to LL questions regarding resources for learning each of the following languages:*

1. [Arabic](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4zbHNqYnTAhXB4SYKHY-uAxoQ3ywIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdQw4w9WgXcQ&usg=AFQjCNEPGa2VKuL0GefK_nkQoh9csTD8OA&sig2=bgA1Cq1XIHpw1-mg331Lxw&bvm=bv.151325232,d.eWE)
2. [Greek](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4zbHNqYnTAhXB4SYKHY-uAxoQ3ywIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdQw4w9WgXcQ&usg=AFQjCNEPGa2VKuL0GefK_nkQoh9csTD8OA&sig2=bgA1Cq1XIHpw1-mg331Lxw&bvm=bv.151325232,d.eWE)
3. [Italian](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4zbHNqYnTAhXB4SYKHY-uAxoQ3ywIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdQw4w9WgXcQ&usg=AFQjCNEPGa2VKuL0GefK_nkQoh9csTD8OA&sig2=bgA1Cq1XIHpw1-mg331Lxw&bvm=bv.151325232,d.eWE)
4. [Portuguese](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4zbHNqYnTAhXB4SYKHY-uAxoQ3ywIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdQw4w9WgXcQ&usg=AFQjCNEPGa2VKuL0GefK_nkQoh9csTD8OA&sig2=bgA1Cq1XIHpw1-mg331Lxw&bvm=bv.151325232,d.eWE)
5. [Punjabi](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4zbHNqYnTAhXB4SYKHY-uAxoQ3ywIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdQw4w9WgXcQ&usg=AFQjCNEPGa2VKuL0GefK_nkQoh9csTD8OA&sig2=bgA1Cq1XIHpw1-mg331Lxw&bvm=bv.151325232,d.eWE)
6. [Swedish](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4zbHNqYnTAhXB4SYKHY-uAxoQ3ywIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdQw4w9WgXcQ&usg=AFQjCNEPGa2VKuL0GefK_nkQoh9csTD8OA&sig2=bgA1Cq1XIHpw1-mg331Lxw&bvm=bv.151325232,d.eWE)
   (...and so on)

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know we had-- Oh, you... +10 Internet troll points

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I say, let's go for it (probably). Something to note - [Japanese.SE has a massive list of resources](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/756/19139), [as well as Spanish.SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514). (I haven't checked any of the other language sites yet.) With that in mind, should we leave those lists up to the language specific sites, should we link to their sites from our megathread, or should we ignore their posts, or what?

Also note that their lists are on their meta sites, maybe we want ours in meta as well.

Probably.

Comment: Italian.SE also has a good resource: [What good reference works on Italian are available online?](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/122/2505)

Comment: If there are other sites that have resources on learning a specific language like the links you have, our meta post should link back straight to them. Otherwise, just add those resources in a CW answer

Comment: Note the Spanish question was moved to the main site --> https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/